# How to toggle image in html and also store 0 or 1 in flag variable?

Tags: html

I want a star icon image will be displayed at a time,contains two star icons, one is blank and another is yellow in colour and will be swapped as clicked or tap for touch screen devices.

And one more thing,I need is while swapping,I want to store values as 0 or 1 in flag variable.star1.jpg(blank/dull star) represent as 0 value.star2.jpg(yellow star) represents as 1.

Real life example in google restaurant result,right side star button.
http://gilsmethod.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/google-hotpot-recommendations-android-maps.png

I want simple coding.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="91%">Restaurant 1</td>
                        <td>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img border="0"
                                    src="star1.jpg"
                                    width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" >
                                </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Restaurant 2</td>
                        <td>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img border="0"
                                    src="star1.jpg"
                                    width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" >
                                </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if the world solved our problems every time we said **we want** something? Unfortunately, that's not how the world turns. Show us what you've already tried. You showed the HTML, but that's simply the structure. What have you tried to toggle the stars on click and to set a value in your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm correct, is this the answer that you are looking for.
Also the only tag with your question is HTML, but I think you are looking for a JS solution because you are talking about variabels.

you could add an onclick event to change your star

```
<img src="star1.jpg" onclick="changeStar(this)">
```

and then write inside your JS file or `<script></script>` tag

```
var flag-variable = 0;
function changeStar(star){
    if(flag-variable == 0){//blank
        star.src = "star2.jpg";
        flag-variable = 1;
    }else{//yellow
        star.src = "star1.jpg";
        flag-variable = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: somehow its not working,tested on html in ibm worklight and tested on jsfiddle,link:https://jsfiddle.net/sphakrrokr/z91zg29t/1/

Comment: strange, I tested it in my browser (firefox, chrome) without any problems

Comment: OK,its working on my ibm worklight console,but not in jsfiddle.net/sphakrrokr/z91zg29t/1 with alert() given,changeStar() not executing in jsfiddle.

Comment: one more thing is that each list item should have its own variable or an array,otherwise the value 0 or 1 will be shared by all list items,which is wrong.

Comment: True, If you want to store values as 0 or 1, you have to do_that_. I recommand the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think that table layout isn't best HTML mockup in your case (But you can modify and apply this javascript if you want).

So, check this out (I've tested for mobile and it works).
http://www.jqueryrain.com/2014/08/bootstrap-rating-jquery-rating-plugin/

Here are other examples:
http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-rating-plugin/

Comment: Thanks for the rating part but what about the toggle and storing value as 0 or 1 as swapped?

Comment: rating consists of multiple stars I just want to make an item as favorite and toggle it,that is favorite the item or unfavorite it.